# Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 went from functional to completely dead in 12 hours

Tags: data-recovery, power-on, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

My Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 tablet was working normally before bed. When I woke up, the screen had gone to just grey stripes like a bad test pattern, and I couldn't turn it off whatever I did, so I left it on hoping it would drain the battery and then I could restart it. However it won't turn on whatever I do now.

I have been charging it for days and it's completely dead. Samsung said they thought it was the power cable, but that doesn't explain why it cannot turn on and the grey stripes.

I have pretty much kissed it goodbye but need photos and other files off it, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]. This is a Q&A site best for specific question. As of current, I read about 3 interrelated issues here: power, screen, and data recovery. This make this question too broad, so could you clarify which one do you want to have answered first? You can browse some existing questions on [tag:data-recovery]. Otherwise, please ask each specific issue on separate post.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the battery, but that might not solve the problem. 
When I had similar problem, there was nothing I could do about it, because the charging unit inside the device was dead. But I'm sure it has something to do with the battery, your best option would probably be sending it to a help / service / repair center...